# How to create a CMAKE Script to build a C++ app with embedded Python?

Tags: c++, cmake

To Compile a C app with embedded Python, for s simple project the following works great:

```
  gcc -std=c99 -ggdb3 -O0 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra \
  -fpie $(/opt/python/38/bin/python3-config   --cflags --embed) -o 'app' \
  'main.c' $(/opt/python/38/bin/python3-config --embed --ldflags)
```

To compile and run this code:

```
   #define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
   #include <python3.8/Python.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);

    Py_SetProgramName(program);
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print(list(range(0,5)))");

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
    
   }
```

How would you you build that with CMAKE?

Tried:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(app C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(app main.c)

execute_process(COMMAND python3-config --cflags  --embed OUTPUT_VARIABLE PY_CFLAGS)
execute_process(COMMAND python3-config --ldflags --embed OUTPUT_VARIABLE PY_LDFLAGS)

SET(PY_CFLAGS  "-std=c99 -ggdb3 -O0 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -fpie ${PY_CFLAGS}")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS  "${PY_LDFLAGS}")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${PY_CFLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${PY_LDFLAGS}")
```

But doesn't work, and ends up with: undefined reference to `main'.
Any Advice

Comment: A **linkage** should be performed via `target_link_libraries`, setting `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is insufficient for that purpose. Call `python3-config` with `--libs` option and use its output (after stripping possible `-l` prefix) in `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: Thank you very much, that led me to the right answer. CMAKE is a horribly documented tool. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working CMAKE Script, that successfully compiles a C program that embeds Python (Via #include <Python.h>)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(myapp C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(myapp main.c) 

include_directories(/opt/python/38/include/python3.8)
link_directories(/opt/python/38/lib)

target_link_libraries(myapp python3.8 crypt pthread dl util m)
```